# Jhipster - Angular HTTP Get request never executed

Tags: spring, angular, rest, model-view-controller, jhipster

I use JHipster Framework on a Web Project. I'm new to it so I have some questions. I try to implement an API call from a button to the back-end. I want the button `Resolve` when it's clicked to call a method and this method goes to the service to make the actual API call.
Now there is the problem.
When i access the resolveFile method in my Service i get all the alerts but not the API call.
When I try to access directly the backend making the call from Postman it works well. The problem seems to be in the **myFile.service.ts** file. Do you have any suggestions?

**myFile.component.html:**

```
<button (click)="resolveFile(myfile.id)" class="btn-dark btn btn-sm">
    <span class="fa fa-beer"></span>
    <span class="d-none d-md-inline" >Resolve</span>
</button>
```

**myFile.component.ts:**

```
resolveFile(id) {
    alert('mpika1');
    this.myfileService.resolveFile(id);
}
```

**myFile.service.ts**

```
private resourceUrl = SERVER_API_URL + 'api/my-file/resolve';
resolveFile(id: String): Observable<EntityResponseType> {
    debugger;
    alert();
    this.http.get(`${this.resourceUrl}/${id}`);
    alert();
    return null;
}
```

**myFileResource.java**

```
@GetMapping("/my-file/resolve/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<MyFileDTO> resolveFile(@PathVariable String id)
{
    log.debug("REST request to resolve myFile: {}", id);

    // TODO
    myService.resolveFile(id);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subscribe it.

```
this.http.get(`${this.resourceUrl}/${id}`).subscribe((res) =>{
  //res -> response output
});
```

Angular uses library called **rxjs**, for more info https://angular.io/guide/rx-library

For better implementation, better return the `Observable` rather than returning `null`

**myFile.service.ts**

```
private resourceUrl = SERVER_API_URL + 'api/my-file/resolve';
resolveFile(id: String): Observable<EntityResponseType> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.resourceUrl}/${id}`);
}
```

**myFile.component.ts**

```
resolveFile(id) {
   //In here you could wait the response
    this.myfileService.resolveFile(id).subscribe((res) =>{
      //res -> response output
      alert('mpika1');
    });;
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks!! But what does it mean? can you post me a link?

Answer (score 1):

When using observable in angular , and in order to get them to be executed to have to subscribe to it.

```
 resolveFile(id) {
    alert('mpika1');
    this.myfileService.resolveFile(id).subscribe(reslt => {
 // to see the result 
console.log(rslt) 
});
}
```

Comment: What is the right place to call subscribe?
After the http request or at the method call of it like you did?

Comment: i'm not an expert in angular but you should make subscribe in the component and not in the service.